# Why does ifup seemingly ignore sysctl settings?

Tags: centos, ipv6, sysctl

On a new CentOS 7 system, I'm trying to disable ipv6.

I've added the following to `/etc/sysctl.conf` to do so:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

On boot, the interfaces all come up without ipv6 support - great! However, if I issue `ifdown` and `ifup` on an interface, it comes back up with ipv6 support:

```
[root@server ~]# ip a | grep inet6
[root@server ~]# ifdown enp0s3 && ifup enp0s3
Device 'enp0s3' successfully disconnected.
Connection successfully activated (D-Bus active path: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/9)
[root@server ~]# ip a | grep inet6
    inet6 2601:681:201:62b0::45d8/128 scope global tentative noprefixroute dynamic 
    inet6 2601:681:201:62b0:c6b:2fa2:be84:3e40/64 scope global noprefixroute dynamic 
    inet6 fe80::9997:e614:3fdd:a0ba/64 scope link noprefixroute 
[root@server ~]#
```

If I "re-run" `sysctl`, the ipv6 addresses are removed:

```
[root@server ~]# sysctl -p
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
[root@server ~]# ip a | grep inet6
[root@server ~]#
```

- What gives? It seems that `ifup` runs without respect to the settings in `sysctl`. I thought settings in `sysctl.conf` were "permanent". Am I misunderstanding something?
- Is there a way to avoid needing to execute `sysctl -p` after every execution of `ifup`?